# Android - recognise HOME button press in service.class

Tags: android, android-service, android-homebutton

I'm developing a permanent homescreen overlay dialog, since there is a 5 second delay when a service starts a activity after pressing home button I was forced to put my activity code in a service too. my app works fine, but the overlay remains on screen when the user is pressing home or back button. is there ANY way to detect if the user pressed home or back in a service .class that I can call `selfStop()` and remove the view from screen? In a activity I could use onStop to check if home button is pressed but since there is no `onStop()` in a service I'm stuck.

Any way to get the home button to react like intended?

Comment: we have the code to detect in activities ... but it wont get support in service classes..

Comment: so... there is no way to get that problem sorted in a service?

Comment: yes.. sure .. because service is used  to work in background of app..